# Session is not Expired in Vaadin

Tags: java, javascript, vaadin7

Im in the Middle of Developing WebApplication Using Vaadin and Spring. I Used AbstractJavaScriptComponent and Using setInterval() im getting data from the backend and display the data Real Time.

My Question is The Requests are act as User Request Request and Session is not timeout because Vaadin Received it as User Interaction.

Is there anyway to ignore the javascript Connection and activate session timeout according to Users UI Interactions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help you in your specific case, but you can set a servlet parameter named `closeIdleSessions` in your web.xml like so:

```
<init-param>
      <param-name>closeIdleSessions</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This will timeout user sessions which are only kept alive by UI heartbeat events. It's worth a try at least.

Comment: Yes, That is working for normal Scenario this is a special one. When we adding Java script with setInterval() i keep communicating with the backend technically  session is active because of this. so what i required is ignore the javascript requests. answer deserve upvote. :D

Comment: Ok, thanks for the upvote and sorry that I couldn't help you more. Where is this method setInterval() you're calling defined?

Comment: it defined inside the Javascript and im calling Javascript Connector and retrieving value to the Fronend Using that. I will Comeup with the Solution i will post it when it finished. Thanks